# Question about the phrase "items borrowed"

Tags: sentence

In the sentence

> For example, the proportion of children's **book borrowed** doubled to
>   comprise 40% of total

I mean that "book borrowed" = book which is borrowed.
And the full sentence is :

> For example, the proportion of children's **book which is borrowed** doubled to
>   comprise 40% of total

Please confirm for me. The way I mean correct or incorrect?

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Comment: I think that should be **"proportion of children's books borrowed"** - vs. bought, for example.

Answer (score 2):

The first would have to read:

> For example, the proportion of children's books borrowed doubled to
>   comprise 40 % of the total.

The second would have to read:

> For example, the proportion of children's books which were borrowed
>   doubled to comprise 40 % of the total.

Amended in that way, both can be used. The first is more likely to be what a native speaker would write.

Comment: by your interpretation. I understand that, my thoughts were correct.? Is correct

Comment: @BinhPHT you used singular "book" and "is."  Barrie has corrected these errors to note the plural "children's books were" as opposed to "children's books is" or "children's books was."  Otherwise, the substitution is fine.

Answer (score -1):

If all the children possess ONE book, then you may write:

> the proportion of children's (borrowed) book (that/which were
>   borrowed)...

Or, if the children possess many books, you may write

> the proportion of (borrowed) children's books (that/which were
>   borrowed)...

You must choose either method; both are valid.

> They are borrowed books. They are books that/which were borrowed.
>
> It's a borrowed book. It's a book that was borrowed.

I recommend the use of the former to be concise. Nonetheless, either may be used.